# WPF adorned elements flickering

Tags: .net, wpf

I have built a custom timer control that is basically a user control, this control has TextBox controls the have values which counts down while it is working.

This control is added as a child to a Canvas, and when start dragging the control it is placed in an AdornerLayer.

while dragging this control, the working TextBoxes flickers and if you stopped moving (but don't Mouse Up!!) the TextBoxes disappear!!!

I have search for a solution, and in one of them it said to set the adorned element and the AdornerLayer IsHitTestVisible to false but it didn't do the trick

Any help would be appreciated